# Coloring close points

Tags: python, geometry, tkinter

I have a dense set of points in the plane. I want them colored so that points that are close to each other have the same color, and a different color if they're far away. For simplicity assume that there are, say, 5 different colors to choose from. Turns out I've not the slightest idea how to do that ..

I'm using Tkinter with Python, by the way

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you have clumps of points? "Closeness" and "farness" are not discrete. Things which are close gradually become far.

Comment: At least some interesting question not of the series "How to it with the tool X".

Comment: You are right, Noufal. I think it's a bit difficult to phrase exactly, but if the points were equally distributed inside a circle, it would make sense to simply divide it into pizza slices and give each slice a different color.

Comment: The pizza slice doesn't minimize the average distance between points in the same group. so you *really* need to define better what you're trying to achieve. maybe something to do with a symmetric partition?

Comment: Why not? if the points are uniformly distributed then symmetric partition and clustering should be more or less the same. Besides, if the set is dense and you use a limited number of colors, then eventually some blue point should be arbitrarily close to an orange region - else you'd have to color everything the same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use whatever color you want, you can use that fact that colors are (almost) continuous. color the points according to their x,y coordinates, so you'll get as a side effect that **close points will have a *somewhat similar* color**.

You can use something like

```
point.color(R,G,B) = ( point.normalized_x, 0.5, 1-point.normalized.y )
```

where normalized_x is (x-min_x / (max_x-min_x)), so it would give 0 for the point with minimal x value, and 1 for point with maximal x value.

If you really need to use only a small number of colors and have **close point have the *exact* same color**, then you'll have to do some [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) on your data ([K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) being a simple and widely used algorithm). After clustering, you just assign each point a color according to its cluster's id. Python has some good implementations, including [scipy's clustering](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html).

Comment: yep. It seems that the tuning of the clustering is the most difficult part.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best idea. I asked for distinct colors because I thought that would make things simpler, but turns out it is not so. I'll now have to read about clustering. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with identifying the concentrations of the spots in the plane. Find the centers of those agglomerations and assign them each unique color. Then for other spots you could simply calculate the color using the linear principle. For example, if one center is red and the other is yellow, a point somewhere in the middle would become orange.

I'd probably use some exponential function instead of a linear principle. This will keep the point groups more or less of the same color only giving a noticeable color change to far away points, or, to be more exact, to far away and somewhere in between points.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to go through your points and partition them into sets with a "center". Since you have 5 colours, you'll have 5 sets. You compare the distance of the new point from each of the centers and then put it in the same group as the closest one.

Each set corresponds to a different colour so you can just plot it after this partitioning is done.

Comment: I like this idea - but I'm not sure how to choose those centers, and how to make sure each set has more or less the same number of points

Answer (score 0):

The problem domain is the well-trodden [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and the [Cluster suite with PyCluster](http://bonsai.ims.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/index.htm) is a good start.